# Convert FreeType Bearings to Origin Coordinates

Tags: c, drawing, freetype

I'm trying to use FreeType to create a bitmap font for a microcontroller, but I'm stuck on the fundamental difference in the way coordinates are expressed. My microcontroller expects an X and Y offset for the glyph bitmap relative to an origin point in the upper left corner, whereas FreeType is giving me "bearings" relative to an invisible baseline. I'm pretty sure bearingX is what I want for my X offset, but how do I determine my Y offset? I tried subtracting bearingY from the ascender height, but some of the offsets come out negative. This is unacceptable, because it makes drawing text in the upper left corner of a display impossible.

Comment: I don't see why the ascender height should be relevant, that might or might not be at the top, so it is not surprising that some coordinates are coming out negative. Some graphics use the y coordinate top down, others from bottom up. I never found one where the x direction was not left to right.

Comment: I was trying to use the ascender height to determine the location of the baseline. The way I understood it, the ascender height was the highest point from the baseline that a glyph could extend. Apparently this is not the case. How do you suggest I get a Y offset from the top down from a "bearing" that describes the distance from an arbitrary baseline up?

Comment: Go through all the glyphs and find the one that has the largest Y above the baseline. Then add a couple pixels for good luck, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by pre-rendering all of the glyphs, and keeping track of the maximum ascent and descent in actual rendered pixels. Then I calculated the maximum height of all glyphs from the two values, and used that to calculate the Y-offset for each glyph bitmap from its top bearing. With an extra rendering step, I can also re-scale the face to more closely match my desired pixel height.